# Getting decimal from (10:10:00) while trying to load an xlsx excel file with a JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm using [read-excel-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) library to load an excel file with the next structure,

[image: Excel Structure]

The problem is when the code read this value,

[image]

The returned value is the next,

[image: Returned value]

And here is my code,

```
let ExcelLoader = window.readXlsxFile;

let input = document.getElementById('input-file');

//Task  Created by  Responsible person  Status  Created on  Closed on   Deadline    Tags
const schema = {
    'Task': {
        prop: 'task',
        type: String
    },
    'Created by': {
        prop: 'createdBy',
        type: String
    },
    'Responsible person': {
        prop: 'responsiblePerson',
        type: String
    },
    'Status': {
        prop: 'status',
        type: String
    },
    'Created on': {
        prop: 'createdOn',
        type: String
    },
    'Closed on': {
        prop: 'closedOn',
        type: String
    },
    'Deadline': {
        prop: 'deadline',
        type: String
    },
    'Tags': {
        prop: 'tags',
        type: String
    }
};

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log('The Change listener actioned!');
    ExcelLoader(input.files[0], { schema })
        .then(({rows, errors}) => {
            console.log(rows);
            //console.log(errors);
        })
});
```

I'm doing this little excersice client side and I was trying to test other types of values in the schema paramether also I was looking for a converter from decimal to date and decimal to datetime with no success,

Can anybody knows what's going on?

I'm open to use other client side libraries...

Comment: I know that sometimes this type of errors are normal in open source projects

Comment: In Excel Dates and Times are stored as numbers, where 1 day = 1.  Dates are the number of days since 1/1/1970, and times are fractional values. So 10am for example = 10/24 = ~0.417.  You just need to do the math from there...  For example take a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565524/converting-excel-time-to-moment-js

Comment: You got the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Williams says, in Excel Dates and Times are stored as numbers.